# QPushButton dimensions change when Stylesheet is apllied

Tags: qt, qt4, stylesheet, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

When I apply a style sheet on QPushButton its dimensions change. 
This is my style sheet declaration.

```
 QPushButton { 
   background-color: rgb(175, 187, 199);
   color: black;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-top: 1px solid white;
   border-left: 1px solid white;
   border-right: 1px solid grey;
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
   border-style: solid;
   border-radius: 5;
   padding: 3px; 
   padding-left: 5px; 
   padding-right: 5px;
   font: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Image - Before applying style sheet](https://app.box.com/s/08qvqml7dscyt1b64q3obozo9qzxp4gs)

[Image - After applying style sheet](https://app.box.com/s/x8unizku61ah2sp6wz2j3lcic7419pak)

How to keep the original button size?

Comment: You can add `min-width` in your stylesheet.

Comment: min-width affects all the buttons :(

Comment: this style sheet should effect all buttons so …? Maybe you should add some qualification to your style sheet?

Comment: @MarekR It is possible for QPushButtons in Dialogs created by me, however I don't know how to do it for buttons in QMessageBox. Any idea?

Comment: yes it is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment below question: Try add qualifier:

```
MyDialog QPushButton { 
   background-color: rgb(175, 187, 199);
   color: black;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-top: 1px solid white;
   border-left: 1px solid white;
   border-right: 1px solid grey;
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
   border-style: solid;
   border-radius: 5;
   padding: 3px; 
   padding-left: 5px; 
   padding-right: 5px;
   font: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

This should be merged with default style sheet (not override the whole thing) and work only on buttons you need to alter.

See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).